# tactics to think as a computer

Tags: c++, programming-languages, evaluation

I have some question from the exam in which I need to deduce the output of the following code:

```
01 int foo(int a) {
02 print 'F';
03 if (a <= 1) return 1;
04 return bar(a, foo(a-1));
05 }
06
07 int bar(int x, int y) {
08 print 'B';
09 if (x > y) return baz(x, y);
10 return baz(y, x);
11 }
12
13 int baz(int x, int y) {
14 print 'Z'
15 if (y == 0) return 0;
16 return baz(x, y-1) + x;
17 }
18
19 void main() {
20 foo(3);
21 }
```

my question is what tactic will be the best to solve this kind of the questions? I'm not allowed to use  PC of course
P.S. You can use eager evaluation as in c++ or normal order evaluation(output will be different of course, but I'm interested in tactics only), I tried to solve it using stack, every time write the function which I call, but anyway it is complicated
thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Seems inappropriate to ask SO for help with your take-home exam.

Comment: I won't help solve it, but follow the functions line by line as though you were the computer. Try using a tree or similar. This is an important concept - learn it well in school. This will teach you to analyze code: if you have to compile your 100+ source file project everytime you want to check a new little function (not debugging), then you're wasting a lot of time.

Comment: @rookie - You'd better hope your instructor doesn't see this post, as it's probably a violation of the honor code at your school.

Comment: He's not asking us to solve it, just advice on how to solve this kind of question. If that's a violation of the honor code, that's a school well worth leaving.

Comment: @biziclop is right, people are overreacting.  He asks for *tactics*, not *the answer*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a "bottom-to-top" attempt:

`baz` is the function that is called, but doesn't call other functions (except itself). It outputs 'Z' exactly `y + 1` times, the return code is `x*y` (you add `x` after each call).

`bar` is the "next higher" function, it outputs 'B' once and calls `baz` with its lower argument as the second parameter - the return code is `x*y`, too.

`foo` is the "top" function (right after `main`) and its the most complicated function. It outputs 'F', not only once, but `a` times (because of the `foo(a-1)` at the end that is evaluated before the `bar` call. The `bar` call multiplies `a` and `foo(a-1)`, which will multiply `a-1` and `foo(a-2)` and so on, until `foo(1)` is evaluated and returns 1. So the return code is `a * (a-1) * ... 2 * 1`, so `a!`.

This is not a complete analysis, f.e. we don't know in which order the characters will be output, but it is a rough scheme of what happens - and as you and other people in the comments pointed out, this is what you want - tactics instead of a complete answer.

Answer (score 1):

What I'd probably do is to start with the `main()` function at the top left corner of the page, write down the first line executed, keeping track of local variables etc., then write the next line under it and so on.

But when a function is called, also move right by one column, writing down the function's name and the actual value of the input arguments for that invocation first and then proceding with the lines in that function.

When you return from the function, move left and write the return value between the two columns.

Also, keep a separate area for the "standard output", where all the printed text goes.

These steps should take you through most of "think like a computer" problems.